# skip after_filter in controller before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using [Intercom rails](https://github.com/intercom/intercom-rails) in my application and I would like to not include intercom script in a certain situation. So, I would like to skip the intercom after_filter when a value is set in the user session.
I tried that, but it didn't worked:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :verify_session

  def verify_session
    if skip_intercom?
      self.class.skip_after_filter :intercom_rails_auto_include
    end
  end
end
```

Any idea if it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the `intercom_rails_auto_include` being set? Because Could you not just put `skip_after_filter_intercom_rails_auto_include` at the top your of your application controller. Or alternatively try and do the following `skip_after_filter IntercomRails::AutoIncludeFilter` at the top of your controller.

Comment: It's added automatically by the intercom_rails gem. I just skipped the after filter :intercom_rails_auto_include to all my controllers and then created a new after filter that verifies and call :intercom_rails_auto_include if needed. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

@Rafael Caricio i faced the same issue but later i have added the below filter in all of my controllers where i don't want intercom to add:

```
skip_after_filter :intercom_rails_auto_include
```

and it is working fine for me